# Pause macro, open user selected report then continue

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which points to a specific file name that is used in the middle. I'd like to change that so the macro is paused, the user can select the file in question, and the macro continues with the details below.

```
Windows("Log 2017-09-29.xlsx").Activate
Sheets("Dates and Financials").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.unmerge
Range("A1").Activate
```

Comment: You can use a file picker: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa219843(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-filedialog-property-excel

Comment: The macro wouldn't "pause". Rather it would prompt for a file name. Tip: read up on avoiding `Select` and `Activate` before you write any more code :)